# Show hidden content when hovering a div

Tags: html, css, animation

How can i create this animation on this website:

https://www.beepi.com/

When you hover on the blue and green circle makes that animation, i want to do the same with this design:

[image]

What should i use and do it? Any tutorials, guides, something ? That i can see and be capable to implement it on my site.

Comment: What about your code buddy?

Comment: What have you currently tried? Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I dont have any yet, im just looking for what i should search and understand so i implement when i start, its better to do structure and all and then ask ? If, so im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make that effect. Here's what I've done:[DEMO JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiureznicencu/4dyq1dgk/).

```js
function js1(x) {
  x.style.animation = "anime 5s";
}

function js2(x) {
  x.style.animation = "anime1 5s";
}
```

```css
#first {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  top: 200px
}
#sec {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  top: 200px
}
@Keyframes anime {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -400px;
  }
}
@Keyframes anime1 {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="first" onmouseenter="js1(this)"></div>
<div id="sec" onmouseenter="js2(this)"></div>
```

**Fell free to use the code**. Now You must only resolve the problem with scroll(the page must go left-I don't know how to do that but I'll try).

I used **javascript** and **onmouseenter** to create the hover part. You can read about onmouseenter [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp) and about @Keyframes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp).